# Why did I lose my Crest (Ribbon)? Am I being punished?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently played a whole bunch of games on ARAM where you have to play a random champion. I am not the best at figuring champions out in 10 minutes but I barely did any worse than anyone else and even did awesome comparing to anyone else when I got a champion I was familiar with.

The fact is that after playing there I lost my ribbon. I still have all my honors. 
I did dodge one game because I thought something was happening but that is the first game i dodged in my life so i don't think that is the reason why I lost my badge.

Any idea what has happened?

Comment: its not showing up in the loading screen anymore?

Comment: Not sure, may be a bug in all honesty. I would bring it up as an issue on the League forums and you might be able to get help from someone from RIOT, any answer you would get on here would be based on speculation at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "honors" you see in your profile are the number of times you've been honored, not the amount of honor you have.  Each time you're honored, you gain a quantity of honor depending on who honored you.  If someone rarely hands out honor, its "worth" more than someone who honors each and every time he plays a game.  There is no way to know your exact honor value, they keep that number secret on purpose.

As stated in the [Honor System FAQ](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/22083111-Tribunal-Honor-System-FAQ), honor can decay over time, and this may cause your Crests (ribbons) to disappear.  Crests are not permanent by design, you have to constantly keep playing and receive honor from your fellow players to keep a Crest.

Comment: is there any way i can view what honor ribbons I have?

Comment: When you receive a crest, you are shown a Congratulations message when you first log in. After that point, you can view the crests through the champion selection/loading screens.  Your opponents can see if you have an Honorable Opponent crest (neither you, nor your allies, can see this one).  Both you and your allies can see the most difficult to unlock of your other crests.  They have plans to improve upon this in the future, possibly allowing you to pick the crest displayed, or to display all of your crests at once.